# Split Python list field into two and leave them in place

Tags: python, python-3.x, analytics, metrics

How would you split a field in Python and then leave the two fields side by side in the list? Is there a command to use asides from `.split()`? Or would it make more sense to write a function that does this? How would it be done across multiple lists

Performance is not a major concern. Below is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Edit: I don't mind using `split()`, I just wanted to know **how** something like this could be implemented.

**List before formatting**

```
['Intel', 'Core', 'i5-4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']
```

**List after formatting**

```
['Intel', 'Core', 'i5', '4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do so, using list comprehension and `split()`:

```
data = ['Intel', 'Core', 'i5-4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']

new_data = [element for item in data for element in item.split("-")]
print(new_data)  # ['Intel', 'Core', 'i5', '4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']
```

---

The equivalent with for loops would be:

```
new_data = []
for item in data:
    for element in item.split("-"):
        new_data.append(element)
print(new_data)  # ['Intel', 'Core', 'i5', '4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehensions to the rescue.

```
data = ['Intel', 'Core', 'i5-4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']
result = [y for x in data for y in x.split('-')]
# ['Intel', 'Core', 'i5', '4210Y', '@', '1.50GHz', '(20%)', '998', 'N']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing something like

```
string = '-'.join(list)
list = string.spit('-')
```

Which would work fine here, although alternaively you could use the `list.insert(item, index)` method if this way causes problems.

Comment: I would avoid naming your list 'list'.

Comment: yea, shouldn't do that in actual code, I was just demonstrating the functions, when I say list I'm mostly just saying thats what the function expects